# Use closure inside recursion

Tags: javascript

I have a function which takes a parameter to print the last number that would come in the Fibonacci Series eg.if that parameter is 3 then it would return 2 as the series would go as 1,1,2
My function

```js
function recursionFib(num){
    if(num==0) return 0;
    if(num==1) return 1;
    return recursionFib(num-1)+recursionFib(num-2);
}
```

No i want to use closure inside this function in such a way that i could print the whole series and not just the last number of the series.

Comment: please add the whole serie of 3.

Comment: @NinaScholz the series for 3 as parameter would be 0,1,1,2

Answer (score 0):

As you are using recursion, you need a print function which does not break that pattern.

```
function print_and_forward(value) {
    console.log(value);
    return value;
}
```

You can use that in your return statements to print the value and then return it. Specifically, try

```
function recursionFib(num){
    if(num==0) return print_and_forward(0);
    if(num==1) return print_and_forward(1);
    return print_and_forward(recursionFib(num-1)+recursionFib(num-2));
}
```

That will print the computation tree. If you want just the series only print the result of `recursionFib(num-1)` and then the total.

Comment: how can i print the result of recursionFib(num-1)?

Comment: @VikramPrasad `print_and_forward(recursionFib(num-1))`

Comment: like `return print_and_forward(recursionFib(num-1)) + recursionFib(num-2);`??

Comment: @VikramPrasad Yep.

Comment: But it prints an unwanted series and not a Fibonacci series.